# SSIS export data From Excel Files

Tags: excel, ssis, export, ssis-2012

I have several excel files, some one are macro enabled or not and the count of file not possible to determine. I need to export data from excel to sql table. I have created SSI package with Foreach loop. But my problem is some excel columns value will be mixed type ie; in first column value will be 1,2,3,four,five,6,7 or first some rows have formula other have not.

In such type when export data some values coming as NULL. I have created excel connections dynamically
and give IMEX=1 in connection string but not working. Note that when I create a single excel connection with one excel file it is working ?

Answer (score 0):

CHECK FOR :
"HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.
IF you are importing to a excel file Check Extended properties
 The driver doesn't care which of the values you use for Extended Properties when you are importing from Excel 2007. The driver infers the proper Excel file format from the existing input file. You do not need 
Extended Properties = "Excel 12.0 
but for Exporting from a excel file you need the Extended Properties = "Excel 12.0. Hope it works